# Event without postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In chat scripts new lines adds without reloading page. User's availability status changes without postback. Even in facebook a new comment adds without reloading page. How to fire an event in ASP.NET using C# so that event takes place with reloading the page.

I believe that its not possible using C#. Is there any special library for it in AJAX or jQuery or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done using native XML components available from the browser when writing JavaScript. These are used to call a server-side page or service to load a block of HTML (or XML) async, and then write it into the document. This is essentially AJAX.

JQuery is a library designed to make writing cross browser compatible scripts easier, and offers built in functionality to help make those AJAX calls for you, without you needing to do the low level bits yourself.

ASP.NET has a range of tools for creating AJAX enabled sites, and recent versions now incorporate jQuery for the client side parts, without you needed to do much wiring up. Together the tools make exposing and calling ASP.NET services really easy. The simplest form is probably the [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/). It's a good place to start if you have never made an AJAX enabled site before.

Also take a look at the [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery itself allows you to send GET and POST Ajax requests and manipulate with HTML elements

```
$.post(...

$.get(...
```